# Find all URLs to certain website in JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have 450,000 lines of JSON with a bunch of them having URLs in quotes that I need a list of.

E.x. `"https://www.example.com/mycompany/image.img/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456"`

The only times `https://www.example.com/mycompany/` appears is in the links that I want.

Is there an easy way to make a script that finds all the instances with `https://www.example.com/mycompany/` and grabs all the text in the quotes? I can't remember what I need to google to find the docs on how to do this.

Comment: Do you have any code that shows what you have attempted so far?

Comment: @vealkind I don't know where to start

Comment: @NoahG- start with figuring out how to read a JSON file first then worry about how to extract the links you want after.  There are numerous examples on SO that can show you how to read JSON you can use to get started, [python- parsing values from a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Comment: Can you include a short  "example" JSON snippet to your question, then we could reproduce the problem and provide a possible solution.